# ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory atomicity

Tags: winapi

Are `ReadProcessMemory()` and `WriteProcessMemory()` atomic when reading/writing a machine-word (32 bits under 32-bit mode and 64 bits for 64-bit mode) from/to properly aligned memory location?

*PS. There is a tag 'readprocessmemory' available in SO, but no tag 'writeprocessmemory'. Perhaps it should be created by someone with enough rights?*

Comment: Windows doesn't provide any guarantee.  Still atomic, the processor guarantees it.  There's no guarantee that code in the process can actually see the update, you are poking memory without any synchronization at all.  Unless you add it.

Comment: There is no atomicity guarantee. It could legally copy the memory byte by byte. (And for small buffers, it probably does.)

Answer (score 2):

If MSDN doesn't state that they provide atomicity on aligned machine-word reads & writes (which it doesn't), then they don't; even if they underlying implementation does, either through HW or software mechanisms you cannot rely on this, this is especially true for code that my be in the I-cache and must be flushed with `FlushInstructionCache`.

If you want an atomic read/write, you need to use one explicitly, in conjunction with `VirtualProtect` and possibly some additional tricks if you are writing outside your own address space (ie: into a debuggees address space).